# ssh xcodebuild no signing certificate

Tags: ios, ssh, certificate, xcodebuild

When I try to build my app trough ssh with xcodebuild

```
xcodebuild -sdk iphoneos10.1 -target <app_target> -configuration Debug CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY="iPhone Developer" PROVISIONING_PROFILE=<profile> CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=<some_dir>
```

It spits an error

> No signing certificate "iOS Development" found:  No
>   "iOS Development" signing certificate matching team ID "team_id"
>   with a private key was found. Code signing is required for product
>   type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 10.1'

If I run it without ssh it builds.
The CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY is different than the "certificate_name". Shouldn't they be the same? The one I ask for is "iPhone Developer" and the build error is about "iOS Development".

I have tried [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/88470/how-to-use-mac-os-x-keychain-with-ssh-keys/659668#659668) (if at all relevant to my problem).

When ssh-ed and I try `security list-keychains` it lists the system keychain twice. If I have not ssh-ed it shows the user login keychain-db as well.
I unlock the login keychain when ssh-ed to see if it will be displayed in the list and it is not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well the easiest solution was to copy the certificate from the login keychain to the system keychain. Don't know how secure or correct that is.

Answer (score 0):

`CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY` should something like this:

`iPhone Developer: Your Name (3374ZYXN2A)`

You can find it in your Key Chain:

- open Keychain Access
- find your certificate
- right-click it and choose "Get Info"
- Copy the entry in  "Common Name"

Comment: Ok I see. However you need to specify the whole of it only if you are manually signing it seems. I am using "iPhone Developer" for CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY. Oh an I am sorry but I have misled you and others. I do succeed in building it with xcodebuild just not when using ssh with the same setings.